# HTML form working but need a php validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, email

i need a help with this. What i need to do to validate the email in this form? This is a landing page, I want to get the email of a visitor before he/she can visit my content [here is this demo](http://www.de-signs.com.au/test/).

Can I get some tips or the right code to use for this page?

```
<form id="contact-form" action="send.php">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" class="cform-text" size="40" title="your email" required>
<input type="submit" value="Enter Now" class="cform-submit">
</form>
```

send.php file:

```
$visitorEmail = $_GET['email'];
$email_from = "doctordongok@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "New Form Submission! - From: " + $visitorEmail;
// edit here
$email_body = "New visitor - $visitorEmail";    
$to = "doctordongok@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r \n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitorEmail \r \n";    
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
header("Location: http://www.de-signs.com.au");
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php) function of PHP:

```
if(filter_var($visitorEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    // Invalid E-Mail address
} else {
    // OK
}
```

So to mockup your new script. It will look something like this

```
$visitorEmail = $_GET['email'];

if(filter_var($visitorEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    die('Sorry that\'s no valid e-mail address');
} else {
    $email_from = 'doctordongok@gmail.com';
    $email_subject = 'New Form Submission! - From: ' . $visitorEmail;

    // edit here
    $email_body = 'New visitor - ' . $visitorEmail;    
    $to = 'doctordongok@gmail.com';
    $headers = 'From: $email_from' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: $visitorEmail' . PHP_EOL;    
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

    header('Location: http://www.de-signs.com.au');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: <?php
$visitorEmail = $_GET['email'];

if(filter_var($visitorEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    die('Sorry that\'s no valid e-mail address');
} else {
    $email_from = 'doctordongok@gmail.com';
    $email_subject = 'Submission! - From: ' . $visitorEmail;
    $email_body = 'New visitor -  . $visitorEmail';    
    $to = 'doctordongok@gmail.com';
    $headers = 'From: $email_from' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: $visitorEmail' . PHP_EOL;    
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

    header('Location: http://www.de-signs.com.au');
 
 exit;
 ?>

Comment: What's on line `19` in `/home2/designsc/public_html/test/send.php`?

Comment: <?php
$visitorEmail = $_GET['email'];

if(filter_var($visitorEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    die('Sorry that\'s no valid e-mail address');
} else {

    $email_from = 'doctordongok@gmail.com';
    $email_subject = 'New Form Submission! - From: ' . $visitorEmail;

    // edit here
    $email_body = 'New visitor - ' . $visitorEmail;    
    $to = 'doctordongok@gmail.com';
    $headers = 'From: $email_from' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: $visitorEmail' . PHP_EOL;    
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

    header('Location: http://');
 exit;
 ?>

Comment: You forgot the closing bracket `}` for the `else` construct after `exit;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to validate on the client side using a Javascript and on the server side as well using a regular expression on both ends.

[Validating an email with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5's new `email` type for input is here to help you.

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" class="cform-text" size="40" title="your email" required />
```